# differential grouping for equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

I'm having a bit of a problem finding information. This calculator:https://mathdf.com/dif/

Solves differential equations using a method called "Differential grouping" or "grouping under differential with derivative", but I can't find information about this kind of solution method, which has become necessary for me. I would appreciate a link with an explanation and examples of solutions in this way.

I almost forgot, in case it turns out to be important, I encountered this way of solution on this example: yy''-y'(1-y')=0
Please refrain from suggestions to solve by other way, I am capable of it myself, I need information exactly on this method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @William,  Yes, my apologies for my uninformative and incomprehensible speech, but I'll try to explain it again. There is a method of solving differential equations called "differential grouping", but I can not find any materials on it, or examples of its use besides the calculator I have already mentioned. And for some reason I need information on this method of solving differential equations. Actually, this is my request: any theoretical materials and examples of its use.